# How Promise resolve yet result from it is undefined?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How **repos**  in the output is undefined if promise has been resolved.

output to the code is :

> reading from database........
>
> hello
>
> repos are : undefined
>
> reading from repository

```
getuser(1)
                .then( result =>{console.log('hello');getRepository(result.username)})
                .then( repos =>console.log('repos are :',repos));
```

related asynchronous function are

```
function getuser(id){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('reading from database........')
        resolve({id:id , username:"sunil"});
    }, 5000);
});
```

}

```
function getRepository(username){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('reading from repository')
        resolve(['repos1','repos2','repos3']);  
    }
     ,3000);
})
```

}

Comment: You have to return the result. `return getRepository(result.username)}`

Answer (score 2):

Your first `.then` is not returning anything, so it resolves immediately. Change to `return getRepository(...`.

Answer (score 2):

your code should be

```
getuser(1)
          .then( result =>{console.log('hello');
                 return getRepository(result.username)})
          .then( repos =>console.log('repos are :',repos));
```